# VIM replacing text in 2 columns

Tags: vim

So below is a part of one column-sensitive file from lines 23 to 34. Please look at columns 25 and 26. Lines 23 to 28 are correct as it's supposed to be sequential.

```
HETATM   21  O   HOH     7      -1.609   5.551  -4.296  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   22  H   HOH     7      -1.594   5.971  -3.395  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   23  H   HOH     7      -1.048   4.730  -4.281  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   24  O   HOH     8      -4.693   5.472  -0.557  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   25  H   HOH     8      -3.881   4.900  -0.521  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   26  H   HOH     8      -4.819   5.805  -1.485  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   27  O   HOH     1       0.289  -5.035   5.663  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   28  H   HOH    10       0.241  -4.604  -5.564  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   29  H   HOH     1      -0.399  -5.750   5.605  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   30  O   HOH    11      -1.741  -5.167   0.877  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   31  H   HOH     0      -2.612  -4.754   0.636  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   32  H   HOH     0      -1.819  -5.599   1.769  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
```

However, columns 25 and 26 in lines 29 to 34 (and also lines beyond 34 that are not included here) need to be edited. They represent the ID number of water molecules in the file. So, columns 25 and 26 in lines 29-31 is supposed to be ' 9' instead of ' 1' or '10', and columns 25 and 26 in lines 32-34 are supposed to be '10' instead of '11' or ' 0'. And all lines after 34 suffers from the similar problem and I also want to change the contents in columns 25 and 26 to '12','13',etc. for each group of 3 lines. So the final result is expected to be like this.

```
HETATM   21  O   HOH     7      -1.609   5.551  -4.296  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   22  H   HOH     7      -1.594   5.971  -3.395  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   23  H   HOH     7      -1.048   4.730  -4.281  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   24  O   HOH     8      -4.693   5.472  -0.557  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   25  H   HOH     8      -3.881   4.900  -0.521  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   26  H   HOH     8      -4.819   5.805  -1.485  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   27  O   HOH     9       0.289  -5.035   5.663  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   28  H   HOH     9       0.241  -4.604  -5.564  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   29  H   HOH     9      -0.399  -5.750   5.605  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   30  O   HOH    10      -1.741  -5.167   0.877  1.00  0.00      WAT  O
HETATM   31  H   HOH    10      -2.612  -4.754   0.636  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
HETATM   32  H   HOH    10      -1.819  -5.599   1.769  1.00  0.00      WAT  H
```

So far I couldn't really come up with a nice pattern to replace those funky numbers to 9,10,etc. It would be great if I could replace all these groups of 3 lines in a single vim command instead of having to do it group by group, as there are 50-60 groups of these with this problem. What I did earlier was just simply `:26,28s/HOH     1/HOH     8` and this is clearly not the most efficient way.

Sorry for not being clear at the first attempt of the question, but your help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your description of what you're looking for is confusing. Would you provide an example of what you want instead? You reference line 29-31 and line 32-34, but there aren't even 29 lines in your example. I don't see `1,10,1` anywhere in your text, and both `9,9,9` and `10,10,10` would break your column-sensitive file format.

Comment: Are you on *nix or Windows?

Comment: OS X/Ubuntu so I'm quite familiar with UNIX

Comment: Ok. I'll work on it for you. :)

Comment: Could you give me a clear example of *exactly* what you want with before and after? If it's too long to post then just link to a pastebin or something.

Comment: Actually please see my next answer. I'll explain more in details

Comment: 9 lines? There are 12?

Comment: How can columns 25 and 26 both be ' 8'?

Comment: This is very confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry again as I don't come here often and may not know the proper etiquette. I'll edit my question and will post here once it's edited

Comment: It's not etiquette. I just don't understand what you want. Show me a single line for how your file currently is. Then show me another line that you have manually edited for how you want it to look. Then say something like: 'I want column 5 and column 4 to swap but only between lines 27 and 51'. This gives me the information that I need. Currently I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Alright. The question is edited. It should be much clearer now.

Comment: It's getting there. But your second line says "Please look at columns 25 and 26." Can you see that there is no way for anyone to figure out which colums are 25 and 26? But I'm starting to understand what you want...I think....

Comment: **Column 25 in line 29** is a blank space `' '`, and **column 26 in line 29** is `'1'`, so I would like to change `' 1'` to `' 9'`. **Column 25 in line 30** is `'1'` and **column 26 in line 30** is `'0'`. So I would like to change `'10'` to `' 9'`. But as you can see, I'd like to change a group of 3 lines only in columns 25 and 26 but I couldn't find a common pattern to do it (due to different numbers within each group). This file is generated from one executable that generates this filetype from another without this kind of details, so it results in some funky arrangement like this.

Comment: Ok. I think I know what you mean. I'm not sure if it helps you but here is what I see based on your question. You have 12 lines and 12 columns. These are apparently a cut and paste from a larger file with more lines and more columns. Each column is separated by varying amounts of whitespace. The lines are grouped in sets of three. The fifth column of each three lines contains a single number that each of the three lines share. E.g. Lines 1, 2 and 3 all have the number 7 in their fifth column. The lines 4, 5 and 6 all have the number 8 in their fifth column.

Comment: However, for some reason, starting from line 7, the fifth column has incorrect values. You would like to replace those values incrementing by 1 every 3 lines? Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. The way I refer to 'column' may be different though, as I meant 1 byte (character) per column, so 'column 25' in this case is the 25th character in the line etc. but what you said is exactly what I want.

Comment: I tried `:29,31s/\%>24c\%<26c/ 9` but it doesn't work. It just place ' 9' in column 25 and 26 without replacing the old content.

Comment: Excellent. So if there are two columns, say: `col1 col2`, does it matter if they are `col1 col2` or `col1 [extra    whitespace     here] col2`? Is the whitespace important?

Comment: Whitespaces are important, so the result needs to be exactly justified like the way I showed. I don't want to go over the file format definition because it's lengthy but I just want it to look like that. Everything needs to be aligned in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but from what I understand, trying to select a rectangular block in visual mode might help you. Use `ctrl-v` in `OS X` or `Linux` or `ctrl-q` in `Windows` (in normal mode).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I just cut the part of the file, and the lines I want to replace are 29-31,32-34,35-37 etc in columns 25-26 to 9,10,11 and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd like to thank everyone for your time and sorry for causing the confusions. I found a way to do it, with python's string formatting as the pattern is really fuzzy and I'm not so used to the regex patterns so I couldn't figure a simple way to do it on VIM.